# javascript loop through messages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops

I have 3 messages in variables.

```
var msg1 = "hello1";
var msg2 = "hello2";
var msg3 = "hello3";
```

I am trying to create a function that when i click it the first time it console.log(msg1), when i click it the second time it console.log(msg2), 3rd time console.log(msg3), 4th time console.log(msg1) and 5th msg2 etc.

```
$scope.clickMsg = function () {        
   console.log(msg1);
}
```

i've tried loops, timers etc but i could not make it work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Why not use an array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an array instead, and it's a bit easier, you'd just increment a number on each click, and use that number to select the item from the array

```js
var msg = [
  "hello1",
  "hello2",
  "hello3"
];

var i = 0;

var $scope = {};

$scope.clickMsg = function () {
  console.log( msg[i] );     

  i++;                         // increment
  if (i === msg.length) i = 0; // reset when end is reached
}

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', $scope.clickMsg)
```

```html
<button id="test">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

ES6 [Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) based version:

```
var messages = (function*() { 
     for(;;) { yield msg1; yield msg2; yield msg3; } 
})()

$scope.clickMsg = function () {        
     console.log(messages.next().value);
}
```

Unlike other answers, does not require you to use a different datatype and will also work for the locally scoped variables (i.e. non-window scoped variables).

[Try It Online !](https://repl.it/Hbkc/0)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this in terms of accessing the string, I'd recommend putting them into an array rather than accessing the global/scoped object but it's up to you. Anyway on to the code.

```js
var messagesArray = ["hello1", "hello2", "hello3"];
var messagesObject = {
  msg1: "hello1",
  msg2: "hello2",
  msg3: "hello3"
}

var counter = 0;

function LogMessage() {
  console.log(messagesArray[counter % 3]);
  console.log(messagesObject["msg" + (counter % 3 + 1)]);
  counter++
}
```

```html
<button onclick="LogMessage()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use with increment value like this

```
var msg1 = "hello1";
var msg2 = "hello2";
var msg3 = "hello3";
var c = 1;
$scope.clickMsg = function () {
c = c > 3 ? 1 : c;
console.log(window['msg'+c])
c++; 
}
```

Working snippet

```js
var msg1 = "hello1";
    var msg2 = "hello2";
    var msg3 = "hello3";
    var c = 1;
    var $scope={} //for testing
    $scope.clickMsg = function () {
    c = c > 3 ? 1 : c;
    console.log(window['msg'+c])
    c++;
    }
    
  function check(){ //for testing
  $scope.clickMsg();
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="check()">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is using scopes, defining them as

```
  this["msg"+i] = "some stuff";
```

and retrieving them as

```
this.msg0;
```

Answer (score 0):

just do something like this, will work for you, make sure you reset it back if needed or do something, otherwise after first loop, you get undefined:

```
 var msgs = ["hello1","hello2","hello3"], i=0;

 $scope.clickMsg = function() { //angular $scope for example
   console.log(msgs[i]);

   if(i < msgs.length-1) {
     i++;
   } else {
     i=0; //reset the loop
   }
}
```